# $S^{-1}J(A)\subseteq J(S^{-1}A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose that $A$ is a (commutative unital) ring, and  suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $A$. If $J(R)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of a ring $R$, then for $S= 1+ I$ we have $S^{-1}J(A)\subseteq J(S^{-1}A)$. The (usual?) proof of this relies on $AI$ being contained in $I$.

> Is there an alternative proof not relying on this fact, so that we can relax the statement and only assume that $I$ is a subring of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the statement isn't true if all you know is that $I$ is a subrng.  For instance, let $A=\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ and let $I=3\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $-2\in 1+I$, $S^{-1}A=\mathbb{Q}$, so $J(S^{-1}(A))=0$.  But $J(A)=2A$, and $S^{-1}J(A)=\mathbb{Q}$.